# Null check operator used on a null value dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am struggling to figure out an issue with a null check operator. For one, my code is the exact same in another area of my program and I am getting data just fine from it. I have gone over it and over it for the last two weeks and have found nothing that helps. As shown in my screen shots, I am actually seeing the data come in from my API call and the field that it is calling null, is not actually null.  Please help as this is extremely frustrating.

[image]

[image]

Perhaps we can jump in a chat session and I can share more of my code specifics based on questions one would have in helping me resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting null value on `controller.port`, better check null and then render the image like

```dart
if(controller.port?.imageUrl!=null)  
    Image.network(controller.port!.imageUrl)
```

More about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting a null value though.  In my response from the API, the image_url: does have a value. Regardless, having a check would be wise because in the event a new port is created, it wont have a value until the customer assigns one. Even still will this check pass since the API is delivering a value in the key:value pair?

Comment: You can check few cases like, making sure it is  getting data using async method then setState.  Others things can happen, try break point on this controller on debug mode